# Add Contact Page Owner EMAIL ONLY link to Master Page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, contacts, master-pages

I'm in a SharePoint 2010 Publishing site, full license. I'm attempting to add a "Contact Page Owner" email link in a custom footer of a copy of the v4.master that grabs the Page Owner's email address from the page properties: Page Owner, and uses that email address in the contact link. I've tried adding the Page Contact web part; this forces in the page owner's name, and on click pops up some info about the page owner (which includes that email). However, I need that link to say, "Contact Page Owner". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a customized masterpage, you should be able add a simple javascrip\jquery to get hold of the anchor tag and change it's text to "Contact Page Owner".

Answer (score 0):

I've tried adding the Page Contact web part as well, and it became a mess. Try tapping into the Page Properties > Page Owner and/or Page Owner Contact Email. This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638572/get-page-owner-contact-email-and-display-in-sharepoint-2010-masterpage), but here's the answer again:

You need jQuery 1.7.x+ and the [SPServices jQuery library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) version 0.7.2 or greater installed on your site.

Use [GetListItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists) as the operation from SPServices.

I'm searching for pages within the Pages directory, so listName is "Pages". Note that list pages and system pages will need a different treatment.

The CAML View Fields are basically the columns for PublishingContactEmail and PublishingContact. I found those using [u2u's CAML builder version 4.0.0.0](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx)

The ows_ variables can be found in the xml view of the POST object in firebug.

The ows_PublishingContact returns a long nasty string of the contact's information. Fortunately the email address is surrounded by `,#`, which made splitting it into an array and then searching for an email @ easy, but that's why that's there.

```
function get_page_contact_email() {    
    var thisPageID = _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId;    
    var e;    
    $().SPServices({    
        operation: "GetListItems",    
        async: false,    
        listName: "Pages",    
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='PublishingContactEmail' /><FieldRef Name='PublishingContact' /></ViewFields>",    
        CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ExpandUserField>True</ExpandUserField></QueryOptions>",    
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {    
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {    
                if (thisPageID == $(this).attr("ows_ID")) {    
                    if ($(this).attr("ows_PublishingContactEmail")) { // if page email is set    
                        e = $(this).attr("ows_PublishingContactEmail");    
                    } else if ($(this).attr("ows_PublishingContact")) { //otherwise use contact info    
                        var contact = $(this).attr("ows_PublishingContact").split(",#");    
                        for (var c = 0; c < contact.length; c++) {    
                            if (contact[c].indexOf("@") != -1) {    
                                e = contact[c];    
                            }    
                        }    
                    } else { //or nothing is set.    
                        e = false;    
                    }    
                }    
            });    
        }    
    });    
    return e;    
}
```